# How to check inside layout if single post is being displayed?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to render back button in layout if single post is being displayed. I've tried to pass pageContext property on create page in `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.fields.slug,
        component: blogPostTemplate,
        context: {singlePost:true}, // additional data can be passed via context
      })
    })
```

Couldn't access this property anyhow in my layout:

```js
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Header from "./header"
import "./layout.css"

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
        <div
          style={{
            margin: `0 auto`,
            maxWidth: 960,
            padding: `0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
            paddingTop: 50,
          }}
        >
          <main>{children}</main>
          <footer>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()}, Built with <a href="https://www.gatsbyjs.org">Gatsby</a>
            {
              pageContext.singlePost
              `<a href="/">Back to all</a>`
             }
          </footer>
        </div>
      </>
    )}
  />
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

I still don't know to much also about conditional rendering in jsx,  but I thought I could do this such way.

How to check if this is single post, pass the pageContext (where to find it) or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pageContext` will be passed as a props to your `blogPostTemplate`.

```
// example

class BlogPostTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.pageContext) // your page context
    return (...)
  }
}
```

If you are using layout component in your blog post template, you'd have to pass context to it explicitly.

```
// example

class BlogPostTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return () {
      <Layout singlePost={this.props.pageContext.singlePost}> ... </Layout>
    }
  }
}
```

As the @TomJardine-McNamara's answer pointed out, your conditional doesn't look right either. Follow up the example above, you can access `singlePost` as a props in your Layout component.

```
const Layout = ({ children, singlePost }) => ( // extract `singlePost` from props
  ...
  { singlePost && <a href="" ... /> }
)
```

Comment: I can't pass `this.props` to Layout, they are undefined. Do I have to  explicitly extend React.Component? Can I get the props any other way?

Comment: I passed `<Layout singlePost={true}>` from the blog-post.js to the layout, but the pageContext - still can't get this value, where is it?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 Here's a minimal example, you can check the code of `src/components/Layout.js` & `src/templates/blog-post.js` to see how props are being passed into sub components. https://codesandbox.io/s/3y746jp5w6

Comment: also the official docs' React is tutorial is top notch! I recommend going through them if you haven't done so to have a better idea of how to work with it https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you Derek, I thought going through gatsby will introduce me to React the easy way. So class then. I'll read the tutorial for sure. Thank you for the sandbox also.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional rendering syntax isn't quite right. In JSX, anything inside curly braces is just a regular JavaScript expression, so you want something like this:

```
{ pageContext.singlePost && <a href="/">Back to all</a> }
```